# PIL ImportError with Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am having trouble with PIL import Image. I have Pillow installed. But when I try something like from PIL import Image it gives following error.

```
>>> from PIL import Image

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 61, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _TIFFClientOpen
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/PIL/_imaging.so
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble installing PIL in Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867250/having-trouble-installing-pil-in-snow-leopard)